# Getting Error - No function matches the given name and argument types. in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I create a function and inside the function, I used predefined function `array_to_string`. When I try to execute my function I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR:  function array_to_string(integer, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT array_to_string(id, ',') FROM ame.stops where custome...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT array_to_string(id, ',') FROM ame.stops where customer_id=customer_id and driver_id=driver_id
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function ame.fn_get_stopids(integer,integer) line 4 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42883
```

When I use `array_to_string` in `select` statement it's working fine.

```
select array_to_string(array(SELECT id FROM ame.stops where customer_id='31' and driver_id='770'), ', ')
```

**Function Code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ame.fn_Get_StopIds(customer_id integer, driver_id  integer) 
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE StopIds text;
BEGIN
    SELECT array_to_string(id, ',') FROM ame.stops where customer_id=customer_id and driver_id=driver_id into StopIds;
    RETURN StopIds;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2):

the function is expecting an array, but you are passing an integer (`id`).

In your working attempt, you are first converting the id to an array.

You may want to build the array first using [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-aggregate.html)

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(id), ',') 
FROM ame.stops 
where customer_id=customer_id and driver_id=driver_id 
into StopIds;
```

But then you don't need to build and concatenate the array, you can simply do

```
SELECT string_agg(id::text, ',') 
FROM ame.stops 
where customer_id=customer_id and driver_id=driver_id 
into StopIds;
```

You may want to order by IDs

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ame.fn_get_stopids
                           (_customer_id integer,
                            _driver_id  integer) 
RETURNS text AS
$$
DECLARE
  stopids text;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(id::text, ',') INTO stopids;
         FROM ame.stops
         WHERE customer_id = _customer_id 
               AND driver_id = _driver_id
  RETURN stopids;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```